# Plotting 3D surface graphs with lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to plot a 3D surface graph with an xlist and a ylist which are one dimensional lists and zlist which is a list of lists.

```
xlist=  [0, 0.1,    0.22173,    0.3,    0.4,    0.5,    0.6]
ylist = [0, 0.1,0.4,1,2,5]

zlists = [[0,   0.0100954,  0.05117122, 0.0952171,  0.1628218419,   0.1245, 0.0731856],
         [[0,   0.0101496,  0.0516, 0.09716544, 0.16126,    0.1025817,  0.059077],
         [[0,   0.01096289, 0.05788095, 0.137201,   0.1133218,  0.0638898,  0.0334927],
         [[0,   0.0155434802394,    0.10213,    0.120433828182, 0.0620560791526,    0.0318, 0.019],
         [[0,   0.031145105337, 0.12922959, 0.064018969907, 0.021701508055, 0.006237178,    0.002], 
         [[0,   0.11832666, 0.02912328, 0.00511592, 0.0004291,  0.00005,    0.000006]]
```

I have found a suitable function called Axes3D.plot_surface that can convert the data into a surface plot: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

However it requires the xlist and ylist to be 2D arrays too. How could I transform the xlist and ylist into the required 2D array formats to be able to use readily for the Axes3D.plot_surface function.

Comment: Desired result please..

Comment: HI @timgeb I want to create a 3D surface plot with the three lists.

Comment: Essentially xlist is my x-axis. ylist is my y-axis and zlist is my axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to generate 2D grid arrays from `xlist` and `ylist`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

xlist =  [0, 0.1,    0.22173,    0.3,    0.4,    0.5,    0.6]
ylist = [0, 0.1, 0.4, 1, 2, 5]

Z = np.array([ 
    [0,   0.0100954,  0.05117122, 0.0952171,  0.1628218419,   0.1245, 0.0731856],
    [0,   0.0101496,  0.0516, 0.09716544, 0.16126,    0.1025817,  0.059077],
    [0,   0.01096289, 0.05788095, 0.137201,   0.1133218,  0.0638898,  0.0334927],
    [0,   0.0155434802394,    0.10213,    0.120433828182, 0.0620560791526,    0.0318, 0.019],
    [0,   0.031145105337, 0.12922959, 0.064018969907, 0.021701508055, 0.006237178,    0.002], 
    [0,   0.11832666, 0.02912328, 0.00511592, 0.0004291,  0.00005,    0.000006]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.scatter(xlist[3], ylist[3], Z[3,3], s=50, c='r')
plt.show()
```

### [image]

By the way, the [source code for the example](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.py) shown in [the plot_surface documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) uses `meshgrid` too. That would be another way to find this answer.

Comment: Hi unutbu and @IronFist the graph doesn't seem to be displaying the correct information though. For example, when x =0.3, and y= 1, z should be equal to z= 0.12. However it isn't displayed on the graph

Comment: when I rotate the graph, it looks flat at that region

Comment: @user2443944: My mistake. Without `rstride=1` and `cstride=1` those parameters default to 10 and data is skipped (the wireframe becomes too coarse).