# How to map 2 numpy 2d int arrays to object arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Given a function `f(u,v) -> z` which takes as input 2 objects (say BitVectors) and returns a single output value `z`. How do I map two 2d int arrays created with np.meshgrid to 2d object arrays prior to invoking function `f` on them?

```
import numpy as np
from BitVector import BitVector

def f(u : BitVector, v : BitVector) ->float:
  # ..
  return my_float

# Vectors of objects
x_bitv = [BitVector(intVal = i) for i in range(3)]
y_bitv = [BitVector(intVal = i) for i in range(4)]

# Vectors of integers (index lists)
x_index = [_ for _ in range(len(x_bitv))]
y_index = [_ for _ in range(len(y_bitv))]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_index, y_index) # X and Y are 2d int arrays
# z=f(x_bitv[i],y_bitv[j]) with i elementOf(x_index) and j elementOf(y_index)
Z = f(X,Y) # error: function f expects 2 BitVector parameters, not 2 integer vectors
```

How to correctly compute the Z values? 
Expected output:

```
print(X):
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 2]]
print(Y)
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
print(Z)
[[0.1 0.0 0.2]
 [1.2 1.1 1.4]
 [2.2 2.4 2.7]
 [3.5 3.9 3.9]]
```

Here Z contains the computed values. The purpose of the X,Y,Z arrays is to plot a 3d graph as per this example: [Plotting 3D surface graphs with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381335/plotting-3d-surface-graphs-with-lists)

Comment: `np.frompyfunc` is a handy tool.  It's speed is similar to list comprehensions, and sometimes even faster.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misinterpreting the question - you wish to map the output of the meshgrid (X = 2D array of ints, Y = 2D array of ints) into BitVector objects so that you can apply f(u,v)->z to the values.

I tried to do this succinctly with map and reduce functions.

```
#Map X and Y to 1D lists of BitVector values
X_bitv = reduce(list.__add__,list(map(lambda a : list(map(lambda b: BitVector(intVal=b),a)), X)))
Y_bitv = reduce(list.__add__,list(map(lambda a : list(map(lambda b: BitVector(intVal=b),a)), Y)))
#invoke f(u,v) on them and store values in list
Zlist = [f(X_bitv[i],X_bitv[i]) for i in range (len(X_bitv))]
```

The code runs now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a rather straightforward solution:
`Z = np.array([f(x,y) for y in y_bitv for x in x_bitv]).reshape(len(y_bitv),len(x_bitv))`

That is, first we create a 1D list with the solutions f(x,y), and then we reshape it to the desired matrix format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this on my phone, so it's not tested.

```
 fn = np,frompyfunc(f, 2,1)
 c =fn( np.array(x_bit)[:,None], np.array(y_bit))
```